# How to call Snowpark Stored Procedure from Power Apps

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, power-automate

I have created a simple stored Procedure that will take variant data from a table and dump it into existing table. But the hook is, I m trying to trigger that stored procedure from POWER BI through Power automate.
I am able to Call that Stored Procedure from snowflake env. it is working fine. But when I am trying to

call it from Power Automate it is showing temporary duplicate stage being tried to create internally by snowflake.

**This is the Stored Procedure i.e working fine in Snowflake environment. But not able to call it from Power App **

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE db_name.schema_name.procedure_name("data" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'main'
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS '

import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
import pandas as pd
import json

# def main(session: snowpark.Session ): 
def main(session: snowpark.Session, data:str ) -> str:
    # data = {"A":[1, 2, 3, 4]}

    data = json.loads(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_snowpark = session.createDataFrame(df)
    customer_wrt = df_snowpark.write.mode("append").save_as_table("schema_name.table_name")
    
    return "SUCCESS"
';
```

*** Error Log is ***

```
Python Interpreter Error:\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"_udf_code.py\", line 81, in main\n  File \"_udf_code.py\", line 60, in NEW_vendor_insert\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/snowpark/_internal/telemetry.py\", line 139, in wrap\n    result = func(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/snowpark/dataframe.py\", line 587, in collect\n    return self._internal_collect_with_tag_no_telemetry(\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/snowpark/dataframe.py\", line 634, in _internal_collect_with_tag_no_telemetry\n    return self._session._conn.execute(\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/snowpark/_internal/server_connection.py\", line 472, in execute\n    result_set, result_meta = self.get_result_set(\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/snowpark/_internal/analyzer/snowflake_plan.py\", line 185, in wrap\n    raise ne.with_traceback(tb) from None\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/snowpark/_internal/analyzer/snowflake_plan.py\", line 116, in wrap\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/snowpark/_internal/server_connection.py\", line 573, in get_result_set\n    result = self.run_query(\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/snowpark/_internal/server_connection.py\", line 123, in wrap\n    raise ex\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/snowpark/_internal/server_connection.py\", line 117, in wrap\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/snowpark/_internal/server_connection.py\", line 387, in run_query\n    raise ex\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/snowpark/_internal/server_connection.py\", line 368, in run_query\n    results_cursor = self._cursor.execute(query, params=params, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py\", line 865, in execute\n    Error.errorhandler_wrapper(\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py\", line 232, in errorhandler_wrapper\n    handed_over = Error.hand_to_other_handler(\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py\", line 287, in hand_to_other_handler\n    cursor.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python_udf/63e04f21e012b250b0dc17b1c5f31a1977e1cad6e5204e7076b757b5c4a73658/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py\", line 165, in default_errorhandler\n    raise error_class(\nsnowflake.snowpark.exceptions.SnowparkSQLException: (1304): 01b2530a-0604-3d52-0075-20030f2761b2: 000603 (XX000): SQL execution internal error:\nProcessing aborted due to error 300002:355092358; incident 5767226.\n in function procedure_name with handler main
```

First I thought python based stored Procedure will not be in scope then I tried simple python stored Procedure . It is able to call it.
*** when I am simply input parameter, it is working fine even through power apps ***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE db_name.schema_name.procedure_name("data" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'main'
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$
# The Snowpark package is required for Python Worksheets. 
# You can add more packages by selecting them using the Packages control and then importing them.

import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
import json

#def main(session: snowpark.Session ): 
def main(session: snowpark.Session, data:str ) -> str:
    return data
$$;
```

Comment: Did you checked snowflake query history? If store proc call is tracked.